# Counting Common Elements in a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a program to count common elements occuring in all the Strings in a String[] array. I have the following:-

> A  *master* array and a *flag* array both of size 26

Now for each string: I am marking frequency 1 for each *character* that appears in the string without incrementing in *flag* array.

Now I am adding the values of flag array to corresponding values of master array

my code looks like this

```
for(String str : arr)
{
    for(char ch : str.toCharArray())
    {
        flag[ch - 97] = 1;
        master[ch - 97] =master[ch -97] + flag[ch - 97];
    }
}
```

My plan is to finally count elements in the master array that have value equal to input string array's length. *This count will represent the count of characters that are common to all the strings*

But my code has a flaw.

if a String has duplicate elements for example, 'ball' (with 2 ls). The corresponding value of the element in *master* array is getting incremented again.
Which makes its value larger than what I wanted.

So this is what I did.

```
for(String str : arr)
{
    newstr = "";  //to keep track of each character in the string

    for(char ch : str.toCharArray())
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < newstr.length();i++)
        {
            char ch2 = newstr.charAt(i);
                if (ch == ch2 )
                {
                    counter = counter + 1; //if duplicate
                    break;
                }
        }

    if(counter == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    flag[ch - 97] = 1;
    master[ch - 97] =master[ch -97] + flag[ch - 97];
    newstr = newstr + ch;

   }
}
```

Is this the right approach? or could this code be more optimized?

Comment: So what is it that you want to achieve ?

Comment: After `counter = counter + 1;` you can write `return` statement. So that the next if condition can be avoided.

Comment: @procrastinator I can't `return` since there are still other strings left in the array to be tested.

Comment: You could put the entire array into a set, then subtract the counts of the array and set to find the number of duplicates.

Comment: Is your final output supposed to be something like, "The following characters were found in every string examined: [a, ., s, t, #, 7, e]"?

Comment: @geneSummons No.
for example input string[] arr = {"ball", "call"};
in my `master` array I will have = 2 1 1 0 0 0.......(2 for l) 0 0 0 0 0 0 (upto 25)
So now comparing element numbers to the length of the String array which is 2 . I find `a` and `l` are the elements that are common.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO - "The right approach" is one you fully understand and can refactor at will.  There are generally always multiple ways to approach solving any programming problem.  Personally, I would approach (what I think is) the problem you are trying to solve in a manner more ideomatic to Java.

For the entire array of strings you are going to examine, every character in the first string you examine is in every string examined so far, so every character in that first string would go into a `Map<Character, Integer>` i.e. `charCountMap.put(aChar, 1)`  For the second string and every string thereafter: If a character in the string under examination is in the map's keySet, then increment the associated Integer (increment that key's associated value) `charCountMap.get(aChar)++`.  After examining every character in every string, then the keys in the keyset that map to Integers with values that match the original string array's length are exactly the characters that were found in every string.

So far, this proposed solution doesn't solve the repeating character problem you describe above. To solve that part, I think you need to keep a separate list of unique characters "seen so far" in the "string under examination" (and empty the list for every new string). You would check the "seen so far" list first, and skip all further processing of that character if found in "seen so far", only characters not "seen so far" (in this string under examination) would be checked against the map's keyset.  [example code](https://ideone.com/WYZell#stdin)

There is also a recursive approach to programming a solution to this problem, but I'll leave that fruit hanging low...

Comment: That is exactly what I have done in my code. Making `newstr` empty each time and checking it.